# How to organize common reusable components (widgets) in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I found a similar topic [How to create modular MVC components in Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712288/how-to-create-modular-mvc-components-in-zend-framework) but it's about ZF1, and I wanted to know, maybe ZF2 has more convinient ways to implement widgets?
For example, I need to display Featured Products block on several pages but without duplicating the code.

Comment: View helper? Hard to answer without more info.

Comment: Like Tim says, view helpers are the best to use here. Can you elaborate a bit more on your use case?

Comment: I said for example, I need to display a block with featured products on several pages, so I need to load the products and render a template. If I use view helper for that purpose, it turns that the View will call the code what will load data from database. Is that okay? I thought all data needed for View should be prepared before displaying the template.

Comment: One more catch is that I can't add a stylesheet file to headLink() from view helper because it called when headLink() is already done.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with child layouts and partials.

You will need to add a line like to your layout (called my-layout.phtml in my example):

my-layout.phtml

```
 <?php echo $this->featuredProducts; ?>
```

Then in your controller you can do:

```
$view = new ViewModel();
$featuredProductsView = new ViewModel(array('products' => $products));
$featuredProductsView->setTemplate('partial/featured-products');

$view->addChild($featuredProductsView, 'featuredProducts');

return $view;
```

This assume you have some config entries like:

```
'view_manager' => array(
            'template_map' => array(
                    'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/my-layout.phtml',
                                         'partial/featured-products' => __DIR__ . '/../view/products/partial/featured-products.phtml',
            'template_path_stack' => array(
                    'expert' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
            ),
    ),
```

Then you would probably want to wrap this up into a controller plugin or something maybe